# An error is popping up when I try to run my Xcode project called "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT"

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to run a simple button that you click. But when I run the simulator, the app launches, and then the simulator stops and an error pops up saying "Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT". I am completely new to Xcode. Could someone please help me?

I tried the linking and I did some research but nothing worked.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

 @IBAction func Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
     print("Hello World!"
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()



}
}
```

I want it to print "Hello World", but that isn't happening.

Comment: “the app launches, and then the simulator stops” But what about the button? Do you ever tap it? Or does the crash happen first?

Comment: Maybe you have connected UIView Objects to Outlets / Actions that doesn't exist anymore... Try to take a look at your connections... Also behind the print("Hello World!" there is a bracket missing... I guess you have connected one, ore more UIElements with code and deleted one, or more without cleaning up the other siede...

Comment: Can you show us the Xcode log?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the outlets you created are not connected to your Storyboard subviews anymore. You can just check it out doing right-click on you button and seeing if your @IBAction is still there.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out few of these points:

- First check your @IBAction i.e your button action is connected to your view controller in main.storyboard
- Then put a breakpoint in the action function and check if it is executing or not
- Look at the connection by right click on outlets connection and see if its showing a warning yellow sign if showing and put a right connection.
- **- For more information about : [USE OF BREAKPOINTS](https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/xcode-debugging-with-breakpoints-for-beginners-5b0d0a39d711)**

Regarding Breakpoints see these screenshots [image: when you press on your button if its execute then it will pause on the breakpoint with green and if crashed then with red line]

[image: Then if you move ahead with arrow down point (above the debug area in left side you will reach to the next line of code, and play the execution again with play button nearby)]

Comment: Breakpoints are basically used for debugging . You can check my edited answer or go through this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html